# bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect not making left and right borders

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am using bodyWithLoopFromRect to create invisible borders on my simulator. 
But when I run, the borders don't seem to be made on the left and right sides of the screen. My sprite bounces off the top and bottom of the screen, but it just leaves the screen when it goes on left or right side of the screen.

Heres my code:

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {   

self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
SKSpriteNode *ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball"];

self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];

self.physicsWorld.gravity=CGVectorMake (0,10);


ball.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 );

ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.frame.size.width/2];


[self addChild:ball];

}
```

What do I do so that the left and right borders are also made?
Thanks

Comment: log self.frame, you'll find its coordinates are not correct. Do you create the first scene in viewDidLoad rather than the recommended viewWillLayoutSubviews?

Comment: Use `view.frame` to create your edge loop instead of `self.frame` and set the `scaleMode` to `SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill` in your view controller.

Comment: view.frame is giving an error.

And I added the following code.

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
}

But it seems to make no difference, my sprite is still going out of the screen through left and right parts of the screen. Please help.